# Slow AntDesign components in Next.js 13.4

Tags: reactjs, next.js, antd

I am using **Next.js 13.4.9** and **AntDesign 5.6.4**. I am trying to load any AntDesign components with 'use client' mode in my page. In the example below I used Row, Col, and Card components, but they appear normally after page.js of AntDesign library is fully loaded, and this makes the layout broken for split second. Any idea to make it seamless other than using loading indicator with hardcoded timeout?

```
"use client";

import { Col, Row, Card } from "antd";

...
<div style={{display: "flex", flexDirection: "column"}}>
  <Row gutter={[16, 16]}>
    <Col>Col 1</Col>
    <Col>Col 2</Col>
    <Col>Col 3</Col>
    <Col>Col 4</Col>
  </Row>
  <Card style={{ width: "300px", marginTop: "16px" }}>Card</Card>
</div>
...
```

First load:

[image]

After page.js loaded (around 128 ms in local):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

to fix it you can custom rootlayout

creat file RootStyleRegistry

```
"use client";
import { useState, type PropsWithChildren } from "react";
import { useServerInsertedHTML } from "next/navigation";
import { createCache, extractStyle, StyleProvider } from "@ant-design/cssinjs";

export const RootStyleRegistry = ({ children }: PropsWithChildren) => {
const [cache] = useState(() => createCache());

useServerInsertedHTML(() => {
return (
  <script
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
      __html: `</script>${extractStyle(cache)}<script>`,
    }}
  />
);
});
return <StyleProvider cache={cache}>{children}</StyleProvider>;
};
```

and add to root layout

```
<RootStyleRegistry>{children}</RootStyleRegistry>
```

hope this help.

Comment: I've tried this, as it's mentioned in the official documentation too, https://ant.design/docs/react/use-with-next, but doesn't work for me